# Make Twitter Bootstrap navbar with dropdownlist active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a bootstrap twitter Nav bar with 2 menus and a dropdownlist style menu.

My code:

```
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DropdownList <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated action</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

How can I make the menu actif (the `<li class="active"...`) only if a menu is selected, or a a child of the dropdown menu is selected ?

I got this script, but it hightlight the dropdown menu even if no sub menu is selected:

```
$('.nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Cheers

Comment: I don't understand what to are asking, could explain it better ?Here is a JsBin -> http://jsbin.com/ukuvif/1